# Should we use get_template_part() in functions files instead of include_once?

Tags: theme-development, include, get-template-part

I'm using the theme-check plugin to check my theme for errors and recommendations, I'm using get_template_part() in theme files like header.php and index.php but in functions.php I'm using include_once() theme-check is not pointing at these, it's pointing at include_once used in a widgets.php file which is included in functions.php

my question is should we use get_template_part() instead of all include_once() and include() or just use it for getting frequently used markup only ? I know it's only recommended to use get_template_part() but I like to follow best practices and recommendations.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at plugin code from some of the core contributors and other WP experts, I've never seen `get_template_part()` used this way although it doesn't seem wrong. The point of the function, though, is to reuse parts of code which would differentiate it from the need to include a file once. I'm interested in seeing what others have to say about this.

Comment: Those are recommendations, if you're not including template part it's more simple to use include_once().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `functions.php` doesn’t create output, so you should use [`locate_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template).

Example:

```
locate_template( 'php/functions.nav-menu.php', TRUE, TRUE );
```

You’ll find this function in `wp-includes/theme.php`. The first parameter is the **file path** relative to the theme root, the second tells WordPress to **load** it (or not), and the third to load it just **once**.

Now a child theme can override the file by just placing a file with the same name to the same place in *its own* theme root.